"Type Error Fetch Failed" when I start the server in next js
Can anyone help me around this error I am getting this whenever I start the dev server at least in most cases.
I am using next-auth and vercel postgres package which is used for just authenticating with the database. I am not using fetch api directly till now.
TypeError: fetch failed

at /usr/lib/node_modules_20/undici/index-fetch.js:8:13

at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

at async getVersionInfo (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js:215:21)

at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)

at async HotReloaderWebpack.start (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js:607:28)

at async startWatcher (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js:156:5)

at async setupDevBundler (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js:775:20)

at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)

at async initialize (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:78:30)

at async Server.<anonymous> (/home/saadingo/FullStack/lms-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:249:36) {

[cause]: AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT]:

at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)

at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1184:5)

at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1710:5)

at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)

at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {

code: 'ETIMEDOUT',

[errors]: [

[Error], [Error], [Error],

[Error], [Error], [Error],

[Error], [Error], [Error],

[Error], [Error], [Error],

[Error], [Error], [Error],

[Error], [Error], [Error],

[Error], [Error], [Error],

[Error], [Error], [Error]

]

}

}

removed the next-auth package and reinstalled it, removed .next folder
